# how to extract the designated div table data in lxml?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

There is a page i want to parse in lxml，the table data will change into different form when you click on.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import lxml.html
url="http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/FinanceAnalysis.aspx?code=sz300059"
material=urlopen(url).read()
root=lxml.html.parse(material)
```

if i write,

```
set=root.xpath('//table[@id="BBMX_table"]//tr')
```

i get the table data of the  corresponding of

```
<li class="first current" onclick="ChangeRptF10AssetStatement('30005902','8','All',this,'');">
```

what  i get is :
[image]

what i want to get the table  data is  the  corresponding of

```
<li class="" onclick="ChangeRptF10AssetStatement('30005902','8','Year',this,'');">
```

what i want to get is:

[image]
how can i write my xpath expression `root.xpath` properly  ?more info:when you click on `按年度`,the table will change into other one .`onclick="ChangeRptF10AssetStatement('30005902','8','Year',this,'')`

I have tried with selenium:

```
import lxml
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get("http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/FinanceAnalysis.aspx?code=sz300059")
root = lxml.html.document_fromstring(browser.page_source)
mystring = lxml.etree.tostring(root, encoding = "unicode")
with open("/tmp/test.html","w") as fh:
    fh.write(mystring)
```

Open `/tmp/test.html` ,no data in it,how can i get my expect data?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to get second element from xpath result?
This <li> element does not corresponding to your xpath expression, by the way, could you describe your problem detailed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you crawl a website, it can cause unwanted consequences.

Make sure the site you are crawling does not prohibit you from doing so. If they say don't crawl the website, you should respect that.

I see in your code that use selenium and output html file:

---

UPDATE: Desiring to create stable code to work, according to Sers's suggestion that: should optimize the method of waiting for the website element has finished loading. I adjusted the code as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,
                           executable_path=r'F:\chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

list_stock = ['sz300059', 'sz300766', 'sz002950']


try:
    for id_stock in list_stock:
        url_id = "http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/FinanceAnalysis.aspx?code=" + id_stock
        browser.get(url_id)

        # click to element  按年度   (Per year)

        wait.until(lambda e: e.execute_script('return document.readyState') != "loading")
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located([By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#zyzbTab > li:nth-child(2)"]))

        element_per_year = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#zyzbTab > li:nth-child(2)')

        element_per_year.click()

        # get table
        wait.until(lambda e: e.execute_script('return document.readyState') != "loading")

        wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located([By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#report_zyzb"]))
        # time.sleep(5)
        element_tb_per_year = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#report_zyzb')
        tb_per_year_html = element_tb_per_year.get_attribute('innerHTML')

        path_file_html = fr'F:\test_{id_stock}.html'

        with open(path_file_html, "w", encoding='utf-8') as fh:
            fh.write(tb_per_year_html)

        print(f'export id: {id_stock}')


except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")

finally:
    browser.close()
    browser.quit()
```

When WebDriverWait works incorrectly, I think you should use time.sleep. You can google more information about this.

This is image:

[image]

Comment: Worst you can do is to use sleep. @it_is_a_literature you really think sleep is a good way?

Comment: I have some problems with WebDriverWait with a few certain websites, I guess I visit too many of their website url in a short time. There was a website that sent me a popup telling me that I read their website at lightning speed :).

Comment: With WebDriverWait:  When the TimeoutException exception, what should we do next?

Depending on the intended use of each person, accepting incompleteness in return for simplicity is acceptable.
Please don't be too time.sleep stigma

Also added that In Source code for selenium.webdriver there are many locations that use time.sleep.

Comment: Not in the case. Sleep can be used only when it's requires.

Answer (score 4):

Here is HTML you get using your code, table is inside a **script** tag :

```
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl_zyzb">
    {{if (zyzb==null||zyzb.length<=0)}}
    <div>
        暂无数据
    </div>
    {{else}}
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="tips-colname-Left">
                    <span>每股指标</span>
                </th>
                {{each zyzb as value i}}
                <th class="tips-fieldname-Right" data-value="{{value.date}}">
                    <span>{{value.date.substr(2,8)}}</span>
                </th>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
```

To use Selenium you need to wait for page to be loaded. In the code below you can find example with `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser.get("http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/FinanceAnalysis.aspx?code=sz300059")

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(lambda d: d.execute_script(
        'return ["complete", "interactive"].indexOf(document.readyState) != -1'))

root = lxml.html.document_fromstring(browser.page_source)
print(root.xpath("//*[@class='name']//strong")[0].text)
print(root.xpath("//div[@id='report_zyzb']//th//span")[0].text)
```

You can get information for all tables in the page using API requests. Each tab of the first **主要指标** section's table has one URL with different `type`(0, 1 and 2) parameters. Same approach work for other tables also:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'DNT': '1',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/FinanceAnalysis.aspx?code=sz300059',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7',
}

# Section: 主要指标
section_url = 'http://f10.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/MainTargetAjax'
data_code = 'SZ300059'
with requests.Session() as s:
    # 按报告期
    data_type = 0
    response = s.get(f'{section_url}?type={data_type}&code={data_code}', headers=headers, verify=False)
    print(response.text)

    # 按年度
    data_type = 1
    response = s.get(f'{section_url}?type={data_type}&code={data_code}', headers=headers, verify=False)
    print(response.text)

    # 按单季度
    data_type = 2
    response = s.get(f'{section_url}?type={data_type}&code={data_code}', headers=headers, verify=False)
    print(response.text)
```

Json response (formatted):

```
[
    {
    "date":"2018-12-31",
    "jbmgsy":"0.1858",
    "kfmgsy":"0.1836",
    "xsmgsy":"0.1858",
    "mgjzc":"2.8010",
    "mggjj":"1.0650",
    "mgwfply":"0.6603",
    "mgjyxjl":"0.5161",
    "yyzsr":"31.2亿",
    "mlr":"8.51亿",
    "gsjlr":"9.59亿",
    "kfjlr":"9.47亿",
    "yyzsrtbzz":"22.64",
    "gsjlrtbzz":"50.52",
    "kfjlrtbzz":"53.87",
    "yyzsrgdhbzz":"-1.17",
    "gsjlrgdhbzz":"-2.19",
    "kfjlrgdhbzz":"-0.92",
    "jqjzcsyl":"6.32",
    "tbjzcsyl":"6.11",
    "tbzzcsyl":"2.35",
    "mll":"27.25",
    "jll":"30.68",
    "sjsl":"14.51",
    "yskyysr":"0.10",
    "xsxjlyysr":"1.12",
    "jyxjlyysr":"2.04",
    "zzczzy":"0.08",
    "yszkzzts":"80.72",
    "chzzts":"139.58",
    "zcfzl":"60.58",
    "ldzczfz":"79.99",
    "ldbl":"1.78",
    "sdbl":"1.77"
    },
    {
    "date":"2017-12-31",
    "jbmgsy":"0.1488",
    "kfmgsy":"0.1438",
    "xsmgsy":"0.1488",
    "mgjzc":"3.1381",
    "mggjj":"1.4559",
    "mgwfply":"0.6116",
    "mgjyxjl":"-1.4363",
    "yyzsr":"25.5亿",
    "mlr":"4.75亿",
    "gsjlr":"6.37亿",
    "kfjlr":"6.16亿",
    "yyzsrtbzz":"8.29",
    "gsjlrtbzz":"-10.77",
    "kfjlrtbzz":"3.43",
    "yyzsrgdhbzz":"7.48",
    "gsjlrgdhbzz":"6.80",
    "kfjlrgdhbzz":"9.79",
    "jqjzcsyl":"4.86",
    "tbjzcsyl":"4.34",
    "tbzzcsyl":"1.84",
    "mll":"18.64",
    "jll":"24.93",
    "sjsl":"6.51",
    "yskyysr":"0.12",
    "xsxjlyysr":"1.05",
    "jyxjlyysr":"-5.54",
    "zzczzy":"0.07",
    "yszkzzts":"98.08",
    "chzzts":"125.67",
    "zcfzl":"64.92",
    "ldzczfz":"80.05",
    "ldbl":"1.67",
    "sdbl":"1.66"
    },
    {
    "date":"2016-12-31",
    "jbmgsy":"0.2059",
    "kfmgsy":"0.1717",
    "xsmgsy":"0.2059",
    "mgjzc":"3.6042",
    "mggjj":"1.9186",
    "mgwfply":"0.6112",
    "mgjyxjl":"-1.1882",
    "yyzsr":"23.5亿",
    "mlr":"6.47亿",
    "gsjlr":"7.14亿",
    "kfjlr":"5.95亿",
    "yyzsrtbzz":"-19.62",
    "gsjlrtbzz":"-61.39",
    "kfjlrtbzz":"-66.86",
    "yyzsrgdhbzz":"-1.13",
    "gsjlrgdhbzz":"-24.72",
    "kfjlrgdhbzz":"-26.92",
    "jqjzcsyl":"6.60",
    "tbjzcsyl":"5.57",
    "tbzzcsyl":"2.81",
    "mll":"27.49",
    "jll":"30.29",
    "sjsl":"10.74",
    "yskyysr":"0.11",
    "xsxjlyysr":"1.04",
    "jyxjlyysr":"-3.51",
    "zzczzy":"0.09",
    "yszkzzts":"90.54",
    "chzzts":"75.18",
    "zcfzl":"52.45",
    "ldzczfz":"97.77",
    "ldbl":"1.56",
    "sdbl":"1.55"
    },
    {
    "date":"2015-12-31",
    "jbmgsy":"1.0897",
    "kfmgsy":"1.0585",
    "xsmgsy":"1.0897",
    "mgjzc":"4.4066",
    "mggjj":"2.3754",
    "mgwfply":"0.9065",
    "mgjyxjl":"0.2953",
    "yyzsr":"29.3亿",
    "mlr":"20.5亿",
    "gsjlr":"18.5亿",
    "kfjlr":"18.0亿",
    "yyzsrtbzz":"378.08",
    "gsjlrtbzz":"1015.45",
    "kfjlrtbzz":"1002.51",
    "yyzsrgdhbzz":"13.62",
    "gsjlrgdhbzz":"17.11",
    "kfjlrgdhbzz":"14.51",
    "jqjzcsyl":"66.42",
    "tbjzcsyl":"22.63",
    "tbzzcsyl":"12.36",
    "mll":"70.05",
    "jll":"63.18",
    "sjsl":"14.85",
    "yskyysr":"0.07",
    "xsxjlyysr":"0.98",
    "jyxjlyysr":"0.19",
    "zzczzy":"0.20",
    "yszkzzts":"27.67",
    "chzzts":"--",
    "zcfzl":"65.55",
    "ldzczfz":"96.64",
    "ldbl":"1.31",
    "sdbl":"1.31"
    },
    {
    "date":"2014-12-31",
    "jbmgsy":"0.1370",
    "kfmgsy":"0.1346",
    "xsmgsy":"0.1370",
    "mgjzc":"1.5540",
    "mggjj":"0.2420",
    "mgwfply":"0.2640",
    "mgjyxjl":"1.9535",
    "yyzsr":"6.12亿",
    "mlr":"1.94亿",
    "gsjlr":"1.66亿",
    "kfjlr":"1.63亿",
    "yyzsrtbzz":"146.31",
    "gsjlrtbzz":"3213.59",
    "kfjlrtbzz":"--",
    "yyzsrgdhbzz":"39.62",
    "gsjlrgdhbzz":"82.92",
    "kfjlrgdhbzz":"90.55",
    "jqjzcsyl":"9.38",
    "tbjzcsyl":"8.82",
    "tbzzcsyl":"3.85",
    "mll":"31.68",
    "jll":"27.07",
    "sjsl":"16.01",
    "yskyysr":"0.22",
    "xsxjlyysr":"1.08",
    "jyxjlyysr":"3.86",
    "zzczzy":"0.14",
    "yszkzzts":"45.05",
    "chzzts":"--",
    "zcfzl":"69.60",
    "ldzczfz":"99.89",
    "ldbl":"1.38",
    "sdbl":"1.38"
    },
    {
    "date":"2013-12-31",
    "jbmgsy":"0.0100",
    "kfmgsy":"-0.0039",
    "xsmgsy":"0.0100",
    "mgjzc":"2.5136",
    "mggjj":"1.1785",
    "mgwfply":"0.2745",
    "mgjyxjl":"0.7084",
    "yyzsr":"2.48亿",
    "mlr":"-339万",
    "gsjlr":"500万",
    "kfjlr":"-262万",
    "yyzsrtbzz":"11.57",
    "gsjlrtbzz":"-86.69",
    "kfjlrtbzz":"-108.51",
    "yyzsrgdhbzz":"28.64",
    "gsjlrgdhbzz":"--",
    "kfjlrgdhbzz":"--",
    "jqjzcsyl":"0.29",
    "tbjzcsyl":"0.30",
    "tbzzcsyl":"0.24",
    "mll":"-1.36",
    "jll":"2.01",
    "sjsl":"-0.42",
    "yskyysr":"0.39",
    "xsxjlyysr":"0.94",
    "jyxjlyysr":"1.92",
    "zzczzy":"0.12",
    "yszkzzts":"62.86",
    "chzzts":"--",
    "zcfzl":"30.57",
    "ldzczfz":"99.25",
    "ldbl":"3.02",
    "sdbl":"3.02"
    },
    {
    "date":"2012-12-31",
    "jbmgsy":"0.1100",
    "kfmgsy":"0.0900",
    "xsmgsy":"0.1100",
    "mgjzc":"5.1175",
    "mggjj":"3.3624",
    "mgwfply":"0.6399",
    "mgjyxjl":"0.0600",
    "yyzsr":"2.23亿",
    "mlr":"3533万",
    "gsjlr":"3758万",
    "kfjlr":"3074万",
    "yyzsrtbzz":"-20.55",
    "gsjlrtbzz":"-64.72",
    "kfjlrtbzz":"-68.18",
    "yyzsrgdhbzz":"-12.07",
    "gsjlrgdhbzz":"-45.99",
    "kfjlrgdhbzz":"-50.55",
    "jqjzcsyl":"2.20",
    "tbjzcsyl":"2.19",
    "tbzzcsyl":"2.07",
    "mll":"15.86",
    "jll":"16.88",
    "sjsl":"13.29",
    "yskyysr":"0.27",
    "xsxjlyysr":"0.77",
    "jyxjlyysr":"0.09",
    "zzczzy":"0.12",
    "yszkzzts":"56.91",
    "chzzts":"--",
    "zcfzl":"4.54",
    "ldzczfz":"97.80",
    "ldbl":"20.02",
    "sdbl":"20.02"
    },
    {
    "date":"2011-12-31",
    "jbmgsy":"0.5100",
    "kfmgsy":"0.4600",
    "xsmgsy":"0.5100",
    "mgjzc":"8.1000",
    "mggjj":"5.9674",
    "mgwfply":"0.9669",
    "mgjyxjl":"0.7431",
    "yyzsr":"2.80亿",
    "mlr":"1.10亿",
    "gsjlr":"1.07亿",
    "kfjlr":"9661万",
    "yyzsrtbzz":"51.55",
    "gsjlrtbzz":"59.62",
    "kfjlrtbzz":"35.11",
    "yyzsrgdhbzz":"12.27",
    "gsjlrgdhbzz":"11.64",
    "kfjlrgdhbzz":"4.62",
    "jqjzcsyl":"6.44",
    "tbjzcsyl":"6.27",
    "tbzzcsyl":"6.08",
    "mll":"39.14",
    "jll":"38.01",
    "sjsl":"12.25",
    "yskyysr":"0.39",
    "xsxjlyysr":"1.12",
    "jyxjlyysr":"0.56",
    "zzczzy":"0.16",
    "yszkzzts":"38.93",
    "chzzts":"--",
    "zcfzl":"6.76",
    "ldzczfz":"100.00",
    "ldbl":"13.13",
    "sdbl":"13.13"
    },
    {
    "date":"2010-12-31",
    "jbmgsy":"0.5100",
    "kfmgsy":"0.5400",
    "xsmgsy":"0.5100",
    "mgjzc":"11.5200",
    "mggjj":"9.4387",
    "mgwfply":"0.9209",
    "mgjyxjl":"0.4991",
    "yyzsr":"1.85亿",
    "mlr":"7032万",
    "gsjlr":"6674万",
    "kfjlr":"7150万",
    "yyzsrtbzz":"12.01",
    "gsjlrtbzz":"-7.13",
    "kfjlrtbzz":"6.78",
    "yyzsrgdhbzz":"1.73",
    "gsjlrgdhbzz":"-10.81",
    "kfjlrgdhbzz":"0.68",
    "jqjzcsyl":"5.27",
    "tbjzcsyl":"4.14",
    "tbzzcsyl":"6.67",
    "mll":"38.02",
    "jll":"36.10",
    "sjsl":"9.82",
    "yskyysr":"0.37",
    "xsxjlyysr":"1.19",
    "jyxjlyysr":"0.38",
    "zzczzy":"0.18",
    "yszkzzts":"50.99",
    "chzzts":"--",
    "zcfzl":"4.09",
    "ldzczfz":"100.00",
    "ldbl":"23.80",
    "sdbl":"23.80"
    }
]
```

Comment: Added example for Selenium

Comment: Why you removed acceptance from my answer? It’s very strange

Comment: It is no need any ajax knowledge in Sơn Lê Trường's code,i knew little ajax.

Answer (score 1):

We are able to get raw data from their JSON request, after tracking it's data sent to the server, I'm able to locate two requests related to the table report (按年度):

http://f10.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/zcfzbDateAjax?reportDateType=1&code=SZ300059

and

http://f10.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/zcfzbAjax?companyType=4&reportDateType=1&reportType=1&endDate=&code=SZ300059

The first request returns an array of dates, which is the pagination parameter for the second request that returns raw data to compose the table.

Chinese headers for the table can be found inside the HTML, it can be extracted by RegEX.

The following code generate CSV data and output to stdout, you can save it as file by:

`python3 script.py > out.csv`

```
import json
import csv
import sys
import re

import requests


def request_report_dates(code):
    report_date_type = 1
    url = (
        "http://f10.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/zcfzbDateAjax?"
        "reportDateType={report_date_type}&"
        "code={code}".format(report_date_type=report_date_type, code=code)
    )
    resp = requests.get(url).json()
    header = resp["data"]
    return header


def request_reports(code, end_date=""):
    company_type = 4
    report_date_type = 1
    report_type = 1
    url = (
        "http://f10.eastmoney.com/NewFinanceAnalysis/zcfzbAjax?"
        "companyType={company_type}&"
        "reportDateType={report_date_type}&"
        "reportType={report_type}&"
        "endDate={end_date}&"
        "code={code}".format(
            company_type=company_type,
            report_date_type=report_date_type,
            report_type=report_type,
            end_date=end_date,
            code=code,
        )
    )
    resp = requests.get(url).json()
    body = json.loads(resp)
    return body


def request_zh_header_map():
    url = "http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/FinanceAnalysis.aspx?code=sz300059"
    html = requests.get(url).text
    results = re.findall(
        r'<span(?: style=".+")?>'
        r'(?:&ensp;)*'
        r'([^{<]+)'
        r'</span>'
        r'(?:[\n\s])*?'
        r'</td>'
        r'[{}<>\sA-z"=-]+?'
        r'<span>'
        r'[\n\s{(\w]+'
        r'([\w.]+)'
        r'[,\d\n\s\w})]+'
        r'</span>'
        r'</td>',
        html,
    )

    header_map = dict()
    for key_zh, key_en in results:
        key_en = key_en.lstrip('.')
        header_map[key_en] = key_zh
    return header_map


def get_next_report_date(report_dates, report):
    try:
        idx = report_dates.index(report[-1]["REPORTDATE"].split()[0].replace("/", "-"))
        if idx != len(report_dates) - 1:
            return report_dates[idx]
        else:
            return None
    except ValueError:
        return None


def main():
    code = "SZ300059"
    reports = []
    report_dates = request_report_dates(code)
    next_report_date = ""
    header_map = request_zh_header_map()
    while True:
        report = request_reports(code, next_report_date)
        reports += report
        next_report_date = get_next_report_date(report_dates, report)
        if not next_report_date:
            break

    #
    cw = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
    headers = [header_map.get(header, header) for header in reports[0].keys()]
    cw.writerow(headers)
    for r in reports:
        cw.writerow(list(r.values()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to get the data you need cos the table you want to retrieve is loaded via a javascript function that makes an `AJAX` call. But, good news, the things that are involved in it are transparent and understandable.

Here's what do you need to do:

- parse the base page and get the value on appropriate `onclick` attribute of the `li` we are interested in
- using regular expression, get the value of two first javascript `ChangeRptF10AssetStatement()` function arguments - we'll need it for an AJAX response
- make a new request to the `http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/BackOffice.aspx` passing several parameters: current time (seconds since epoch), `ChangeRptF10AssetStatement()` javascript function arguments that we already have and other static arguments

Here's the complete working code:

```
import calendar
import re
import time
from urllib.request import urlopen

import lxml.html


# define base url with placeholders for dynamic parameters
BASE_URL = "http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/BackOffice.aspx?timetip=%s000&command=RptF10AssetStatement&paramReportTime=Year&paramCode=%s&paramNum=%s"
PATTERN = re.compile("\('(\d+)','(\d+)',")

# parse initial page
url = "http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/FinanceAnalysis.aspx?code=sz300059"
root = lxml.html.parse(urlopen(url))

# extract js function arguments from `onclick` attribute value
li = root.xpath('//div[@class="content"][4]/div/ul/li')[1]
code, num = PATTERN.search(li.attrib['onclick']).groups()

# get the current time
seconds_since_epoch = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())

# parse second page
url = BASE_URL % (seconds_since_epoch, code, num)
root = lxml.html.parse(urlopen(url))

# get table titles (just for example)
for row in root.xpath('//tr/th/span'):
    print(row.text)
```

Currently it prints table titles, just to show you that it's working.

Answer (score 0):

*You dont require lxml, you can get all the table data by following code,it uses only selenium. If lxml is a must you can make use of the xpaths in the code, change the id of table to get different table values.[image] *

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("http://f10.eastmoney.com/f10_v2/FinanceAnalysis.aspx?code=sz300059")
allrows= len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="report_zyzb"]/table/tbody/tr//span'))
for i in range(allrows):
  allcolumns=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="report_zyzb"]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']//span')
  print('\n')
  for j in range(len(allcolumns)):
      print(allcolumns[j].text, end = " ")
```

Comment: identation,and how about change `id="report_zyzb"` into others?

Comment: I think all tables have similar structure, change id to corresponding id of the table to fetch